# How do you search for file and replace whats missing?

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I feel lost... Do you use the "find" command or "if not exist" commmand?  Anyone feeling like helping?

Here is my situation:
Writing a batchfile to aid users in an install of new application software.  Not all users have the application so for licensing I need to only install on users that have the software.  I need to be sure its in the same path as the existing software. `c:\apps\newapp.`

I have to leave in the install directory for reporting to work and these two files- `name.ini` and `location.ini` and if they are not there they need to be installed. I need to notify users of the install with a message about completion.

Comment: I'm sorry; this is too large a scope to be efficiently answered. ALSO, PLEASE CONSIDER TURNING CAPS LOCK OFF TO AVOID THE APPEARANCE OF SHOUTING.

Comment: not a problem.  sorry

Comment: This is not a site for requesting code be written for you.  Please search, try some example code to figure out how you want to accomplish this task.  When/IF you run into problems, post the code and error along with the expected behavior and we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I can understand your question:

```
set "notify=not exist"
if not exist "c:\apps\newapp\name.ini" set "notify=name.ini %notify%"
if not exist "c:\apps\newapp\location.ini" set "notify=location.ini %notify%"
if /I "%notify%"=="not exist" (

  echo name.ini and location.ini are not present and need to be installed
  rem code to install here

) else (
  echo Sorry, %notify%
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.  I was close.  I had the same formula but didn't have the notify=not exist added.